# Method getProperty of OleAutomation class of SWT.jar returning null for property ActiveSheet

Tags: java, swt, ole

I am using SWT.jar to create an excel sheet and populate data.
I am using these lines of java code:

```
    int[] rgdispid = theOleAutomation.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{thePropName});
    Variant property = theOleAutomation.getProperty(rgdispid[0]);
```

where `thePropName` is a string and in this problem scenario value passed is "ActiveSheet".
For other valid values it runs without any issues.

The problem is property returned in this case is null with suppressed exception being `Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` exception.

Thing is that it is happening only for Excel 2010. For Excel 2007 it runs smoothly.

Can somebody please enlighten me on how to resolve this.